# Почему LiveData не передает ивент если вызывать из callback?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Вот код в моей ViewModel

```
    ...
    private val billingClientLifecycle: BillingClientLifecycle
    private val _isBillingConnectionReady = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isBillingConnectionReady: LiveData<Boolean> = _isBillingConnectionReady
    ...
    
    init {
        ...
        billingClientLifecycle.setPurchaseUpdateListener(
            object : IapPurchasesUpdatedListener {
                ...

                override fun isBillingConnected(state: Boolean) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Billing connection state is: $state")
                    _isBillingConnectionReady.value = state
                }
            }
        )

        billingClientLifecycle.createBillingConnection(getApplication())
        ...
    }
    
    ...
```

Тут у меня есть `billingClientLifecycle` обьект и в `init()` методе вызываю `createBillingConnection` и вижу, что когда я получаю ответ в `isBillingConnected` то вызывается строка куда я передаю ивент лайфдате, но проблема в том, что во фрагменте где я подписываюсь на этот ивент ничего не приходит, если я (для теста) передаю ивент не в колбеке то все работает

Что я пропускаю тут?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге нашел проблему, сказать честно я совершенно забыл о разнице этих методов

[Ссылка на оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51299672/5709159) :

Based on the documentation:

[setValue()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#setValue(T)):

> Sets the value. If there are active observers, the value will be
> dispatched to them. This method must be called from the main thread.

[postValue()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#postValue(T)):

> Posts a task to a main thread to set the given value. If you called this method multiple times before a main thread executed a posted task, only the last value would be dispatched.

To summarize, the key difference would be:

`setValue()` method must be called from the main thread. But if you need set a value from a background thread, `postValue()` should be used.